# Import from Another Directory is Failing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I read that to use a python file as a module for import, I need to put `__init__.py` in the directory.

I have the following directory structure:

```
data_load
    -- __init__.py
    -- rand_data.py

etc 
    -- __init__.py
    -- test.py
```

In test.py I import a class defined in rand_data and I get the error:

```
python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    from data_load.rand_data import RandData
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_load'
```

Comment: any specific ide you are using ?

Comment: @prashantrana no just a conda installation + terminal

Comment: please put a backtick ` before and after the word `__init__.py` if not people will just see init.py in bold characters

Comment: can you tell how you are testing the functionality

Answer (score 1):

change to the parent directory of etc and data_load and type

```
python -m etc.test
```

This should do the job.

Here a small test case (Assuming you're on a linux machine)

```
## create the test case
mkdir -p import_issue/data_load import_issue/etc
touch import_issue/data_load/__init__.py import_issue/etc/__init__.py
echo 'print("I am", __name__)' > import_issue/etc/test.py
echo 'from data_load.rand_data import RandData' >> import_issue/etc/test.py
echo 'print("Randdata = ", RandData)' >> import_issue/etc/test.py
echo "class RandData:" > import_issue/data_load/rand_data.py
echo '    pass' >> import_issue/data_load/rand_data.py
#
# now perform the test
cd import_issue
python -m etc.test
```

The reason why things in your initial example didn't work out as expected is, that you present working directory was probably `etc`
and if you load a python script in etc, then it tries to import load_data relative to the present working directory (`etc`) and below `etc` there is no directory named `rand_data`, that has a file `__init__.py` in it.

My suggestion to fix is to go up to the common parent directory (This will now be your present working directory) and import etc/test as a module.
The reason is, that  test.py is in a directory etc with an **init**.py so you should import it as etc.test and not call it directly.
Calling a file, that is a module directly with etc/test.py is not really recommended and can provoke some rare confusing situations.

Comment: I added a test case to my answer and it works as expected.
If it doesn't work for you, then there must be a difference / a detail, that makes your scenario behave different.

You you try to provide the smallest possible test case that breaks and shaere it with us.

Answer (score 0):

instead of running command in `etc` directory  `python test.py` run the python script in parent directory of `etc` and `data_load`.

ie what you need to do in terminal is (considering you are still in `etc` directory in terminal)

```
1.    `cd ..`
2.    `python etc/test.py`
```

this will work.

why are you facing error is because in `test.py` python is looking in the current directory for `data_load` module, and since there is no data_load module in `etc` directory it is giving this error.

how to solve above problem

1. append the sys.path in code
2. run the script from project main folder which contains all the package and python module and scripts.